# TomEE custom property provider

Tags: java, apache-tomee, openejb, tomee-8

I am running my application in TomEE 8. I want to read some property from my DB and pass it to application.

I saw one example from https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2014/08/06/tomee-and-more-advanced-resource-configuration/ . may be it is old. it is not working . while deploying application it expect the Resource Type. But example doesn't have Type in resource tag.

```
<Resource id="..." properties-provider="com.foo.MyPropertiesReader" />
```

What is the latest/correct way to load my custom properties to my application from my DB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Romain was trying to be concise in his examples. In his examples, it can be surmised that he was using `javax.sql.DataSource` or `DataSource`. Despite that, though, this will work for any type of resource, even [custom resources](https://tomee.apache.org/tomee-8.0/docs/application-resources.html). There are also already implementations that you can check out:

- [HerokuDatabasePropertiesProvider.java](https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/tomee-7.1.0/container/openejb-core/src/main/java/org/apache/openejb/resource/heroku/HerokuDatabasePropertiesProvider.java)
- [OpenshiftMySQLPropertiesProvider.java](https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/tomee-7.1.0/container/openejb-core/src/main/java/org/apache/openejb/resource/openshift/OpenshiftMySQLPropertiesProvider.java)
- [OpenshiftPostgreSQLPropertiesProvider.java](https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/tomee-7.1.0/container/openejb-core/src/main/java/org/apache/openejb/resource/openshift/OpenshiftPostgreSQLPropertiesProvider.java)

In the page you mentioned, Romain also notes that your class can either implement `org.apache.openejb.api.resource.PropertiesResourceProvider`, or supply a `Properties provides();` method.

Here is a small example:

org.superbiz.provider.MyPropertiesReader.java

```java
package org.superbiz.provider;

import org.apache.openejb.api.resource.PropertiesResourceProvider;
import org.apache.openejb.testng.PropertiesBuilder;

import java.util.Properties;

public class MyPropertiesReader implements PropertiesResourceProvider {
    public Properties provides() {
        return new PropertiesBuilder()
                .p("JdbcDriver", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver")
                .p("JdbcUrl", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:moviedb")
                .build();
    }
}
```

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/resources.xml

```xml
<resources>
    <Resource id="movieDatabase"
              type="DataSource"
              properties-provider="org.superbiz.provider.MyPropertiesReader"/>
</resources>
```

These are the key snippets that I hope will help clear your doubts. Implementation of the datasource is left for you to code. :)